# Get info of ruby variable inside a block

Tags: ruby

I have a method like

```
def my_method(&block)
     begin
       yield 
     rescue Exception => e
       puts "Exception"
       return
     end 
 end
```

And the method is called for 2 global variables.

```
my_method { $memcache_connection1.get(key) }
my_method { $memcache_connection2.get(key) }
```

Inside my_method, I have no way to identify for which memcache connection it is called for. It is simply yielding the block passed.

I need to know which memcache connection is used inside my_method. Is this possible?

Comment: If you _need_ to know this, then you must return that from the block. However, this smells like bad design to me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: This is my usecase: My idea is to check if this connection is live, else reconnect to memcached. Fo this, I need to know which connection is being called first. I cannot simply reconnect both connection 1 and 2.

Comment: Why don't you send `$memchache_connectionX` directly to `my_method`, and then use `$memcache_connectionX.get(key)` inside ? It would allow you to access memcache directly in order to identify it.

Comment: @Caillou : It's a huge codebase. There are at least a 1000 places where this method is called. Rewriting it is expensive.

Comment: If you never want to refactor your code, no wonder you get such design-oriented problems. Automatic find/replace is your friend, just don't be afraid of it.

Comment: @Caillou: you assume they have good test coverage. :trollface:

Comment: @ManojMJ: on a second thought, doesn't the connection handle reconnecting on its own? Seems like it's its responsibility area.

Comment: @Caillou : reconnection happens. Problem is with elasticcache. When we promote slave to master, the primary endpoint remains same, but the memcached client is not doing DNS lookup again. It remains with old data, and still continues to write on its "master" which now actually a slave. Which is throwing error.